# Fabric macOS exceptions not caught at times?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, crashlytics

Crashlytics shows me everything's going great, when in fact several people are experiencing crashes that aren't being reported - yet I do in fact see some crashes making their way through into Crashlytics. I can't understand what's going on.

I'm doing the usual I always have:

`[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Answers class]]];`

first thing in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. I also have:

```
  // We need these flags in order to capture crashes more reliably
  if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"NSApplicationShowExceptions"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"NSApplicationShowExceptions"];
  }
  if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"NSApplicationCrashOnExceptions"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"NSApplicationCrashOnExceptions"];
  }
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

directly before I register with Fabric. I also upload dSYMs every time and don't see any warnings from Fabric.

I've got a bunch of users crashing and sometimes they send us crash logs from either the machine or the window they're presented for crashes. Some people aren't seeing neither the crash window nor are they seeing crash logs accumulate in Console.app, nor am I seeing any crashes in Crashlytics - yet they have demonstrated countless times via videos that the app crashes soon after it launches.

What else can I do to ensure I get crashes reported *always* for a mac app?

Comment: Do you have the API key added in your plist?
see https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

Comment: @battlmonstr this is a question for macOS, but yes it's there :)

Comment: How do you add the API key on macOS?

Comment: @battlmonstr yes sorry, edited my comment, it's there for macOS

Comment: @battlmonstr As I pointed out, I'm getting crashes reported, just not 'all' of them apparently. There are are still some unhandled that some users are able to otherwise see and some aren't.

Comment: That sounds like a bug of Crashlytics/Fabric on macOS. Did you contact them? There are some types of crashes that are hard to intercept (like OOM), but if it's a usual user-land code crash, it is definitely a bug.

Comment: Why all the down votes? It's not a duplicate question because as you can see, I've done everything, and it's working at times and at times not. I've written to Fabric to see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't answer the question entirely, however it seems catching all exceptions / crashes on macOS is tricky (as mention by Fabric on their page). It doesn't help when a lot of the code it's crashing on is inlined C / C++ code. I don't think this is a Crashlytics issue as such, however it looks like a limitation where some crashes, including those force `exit(..)` call deep inside certain 3rd party libraries aren't really crashes and thus aren't caught.